# Create record of bash-commands and its properties

Tags: 16.04, bash, python3, metadata, bash-history

I want to keep a history of whatever I do on bash and its output.

I need to create a DB which can store

1. command
2. path (at command time)
3. command start time
4. command end time
5. output of the command

Can I  auto-append these variables in a CSV file with **bash-commands or python script**

Intention: Study the pattern and optimize for repeated command and see the learning curve while writing/testing a code

*offer directions or pseudo-code if can't solve it full*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you have so far and where you struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

Create a bash script. Use this bash script to log and execute your bash-commands. for example, create a file log.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/path/to/your/logfile.log
touch $LOGFILE
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3 RETURN
exec 1>>$LOGFILE 2>&1
echo "### log command ###"
echo "# start time: $(date)"
echo "# pwd: $(pwd)"
echo "# command: $@"
echo "# output: "
$@
echo "# end time: $(date)"
echo "###################"
exit 0
```

Now you can execute your bash-commands like this for example `./log.sh df -h`.

It will create a log file, add time comments and [redirect all stdout and stderr](https://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions) for your entered command to that file.

Later you can parse your log file and create a database from it.